# Is a Ryzen 5000 series APU usable with NVIDIA GPUs?

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, nvidia-graphics-card, integrated-graphics, amd-ryzen

I may be receiving a Ryzen 5600G APU; but I also have two discrete NVIDIA GTX GPUs (1000 series).

Now, I have no intention of using the discrete GPUs for graphics, only for compute (i.e. with CUDA); I want to use the on-CPU/on-CPU-and-motherboard AMD graphics solution.

I know this is possible with Intel chipset on-board graphics solutions (e.g. HD Graphics 630); but - would I also be able to do this with a 5600G GPU?

Note: If it matters, suppose the motherboard chipset is either X570 or B550.

Comment: What made you think it wouldn't be possible?

Comment: @ChanganAuto: Desire by one or both vendors to get you to avoid mixing-and-matching? Assumptions by driver authors that they don't have to content with the "other guys"' stuff being loaded? Murphy's Law?

Comment: All plausible yet unfounded fears. If that was the case you and everybody else would have stumbled with at least one complain many years ago.

Comment: @ChanganAuto: I just want to verify this before going through with a system (re)assembly and other things...